# Angular 2 Http POST request to send image file to server for s3 upload

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3

I am new to angular 2 and nodejs and so far I have only ever needed to send json objects to the backend with POST requests but now I need to send an image file and I am running into problems.  I want a user to input an image file which is then sent to the backend as the body of a POST request then in the backend the image is uploaded to s3.  On the frontend I have the following html

```
<div>
     <input type="file" (change)="testOnChange($event)" multiple/>
</div>
```

which triggers the following code in the associated component

```
testOnChange(event){
        var files = event.srcElement.files;
        this.jobService.s3Upload(files[0]).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

which uses the `s3Upload` function in the `jobService` which is

```
s3Upload(file){
        const body = file;

        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'});
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/job/s3upload', body, {headers: headers})
            .map((response:Response) => {
               console.log(response);
               return response;
            })
            .catch((error:Response) => {
                this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
                return Observable.throw(error.json());
            });
    }
```

Then on the backend

```
router.post('/s3upload', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);

    const file = req.body;

    aws.config.update({
        "accessKeyId": process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        "secretAccessKey": process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        "region": "us-west-2"
    });
    const s3 = new aws.S3();

    var params = {
        Bucket: 'labeller-images',
        Key: file.name,
        ContentType: file.type,
        Body: file,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    console.log(params);

    s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("upload error");
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully uploaded data");
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Success',
                obj: `https://labeller-images.s3.amazonaws.com/${file.name}`
            })
        }
    });

});
```

The specific error that arises is `There were 2 validation errors: * MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Key' in params * InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Body to be a string, Buffer, Stream, Blob, or typed array object.`  But the logging statements reveal that `req.body` is just `{}`, so that `params` is

```
{ Bucket: 'labeller-images',
  Key: undefined,
  ContentType: undefined,
  Body: {},
  ACL: 'public-read' }
```

So it looks like the `req.body` is empty and the image file is never actually getting to the backend.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Is it some kind of file serialization issue?

Comment: Did you mean to define `res` as a parameter of `.putObject`? It's shadowing the `res` from `router.post`

Comment: Yes good point, I will make the change but I don't think that is the main problem

Comment: Ah, so the way to do it is first convert the image to a base64 string, send it to the backend inside a json object, then decode it in the backend and upload to s3.  So really its just like any other json object you send to the backend.